# Converting columns of Pandas dataframe from strings to float?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df

| ID | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | . | 24,000.8 | 400.9 |
| 2 | 5,000.9 | 79,000.8 | . |
| 4 | 6,650.7 | . | 345.9 |

How do I convert these columns (a,b,c,...) from a string to a float (i.e. changing '.' to 0 and removing the commas in order to convert from string to float)?

```
def string2Float(df,columnName):
    if df[columnName] == '.':
        df[columnName] = 0
    else:
        df[columnName] = float(df[columnName].replace(',',''))
    return df[columnName]
```

Is there a way to apply this function to the dataframe? I only want to apply it to column a,b, and c. In the future I'll want to apply it to column a,b, and c etc in df1, df2, df3 etc.

For example this works for column a in df1:

```
def string2Float(dfRow):
    if dfRow == '.':
        x = 0
    else:
       x = float(dfRow.replace(',',''))
    return x

convertCols = ['a','b','c']

for col in convertCols:
    df1[col] = df1.apply(lambda row: string2Float(row[col]),axis=1)
```

How can i apply it to multiple dataframes?

Comment: What have you tried so far and what went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-column-type-in-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .replace function

```
value = float(0)
CS11data.replace(".", value, inplace=True) #replaces dots with 0
```

The .replace function could also be used to strip the commas. Something like:

```
df.replace(",", "")
```